# \$H_2\$/\$H_\infty\$ control

Tags: control, control-system

Typically, \$H_2\$ control design assumes stochastic noises and \$H_\infty\$ control design assumes squared-integrable noises. My question is about multi-objective control design, namely mixed \$H_2/H_\infty\$ control. If the noise is stochastic but not squared-integrable, why do we need to minimize the \$H_\infty\$ norm of transfer function? In that case, the l2 norm of noise is infinite, I don't see the meaning of minimizing the \$H_\infty\$ norm.